# a problem with GUI using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

at the begining of my application i disable some buttons and according to some conditions these buttons became enabled. my problem is when the user clicks on a button then it does my action its color becomes gray and that when i make it disabled again.
 for more explanation:

button.Enabled = false;

if(Condition)
{ button.enabled =true; }

// user clicked on button

// do button's function

button.Enabled= false; // here the button's color becomes gray and i dont want this attitude i want to be enabled where at the begining of the application when all buttons are disabled its color is qiut simmilar to button's background. So why this color ?

Comment: i still have the same probelm where when i click on the button its color became gray..what i did is when i disable the button i set its BackColor property to transparent and its BackGroundImage to my defualt button's image. but it still the same :( ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I read your problem correctly, but It seems to me like maybe you want something like this:

```
button.Enabled = Condition; // Initial value


// user clicked on button
button.Enabled= false; 
 ... do button's function ...
button.Enabled = Condition
```

This should restore the state of the button as before the click, basically just disabling it while processing is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

The disabled state for most winform controls is largely fixed by the Win32 control set. If  you don't like it, then either:

- don't **actually** disable it - just change the color manually, disable tab-stops, and ignore clicks while it is "kinda-disabled"
- use WPF, which has a completely separate implementation and doesn't suffer from the Win32 roots
- write your own button control from scratch (don't touch the Win32 one)
- use a 3rd-party button control

Comment: Do you need to write a button from scratch? It isn't too much work to inherit from the system Button class to customise the render behaviour. I wish it was easier for a disabled control to still display a tooltip to explain why it's disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Change the color after disabling the button

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues with TextBox's before.  The best way to avoid this problem is to just reset the color after disabling the Button.

```
var color = button.BackgroundColor;
button.Enabled = false;
button.BackgroundColor = color;
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2007/02/12/readonly-textbox-that-doesn-t-look-funny.aspx